# Use variable in invoke-webrequest -Uri path

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create function to download a file from internet where the path to the files is defined in multiple text files on different client computers.

This is what I have come up with so far.

```
$Company = Get-Content "C:\ProgramData\test\Company.txt"
$CompanyURLFile = "https://onegeek.dk/MSI/$Company.rar"
$CompanyUpdateFile="C:\ProgramData\test\conf\conf.rar"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $CompanyURLFile -OutFile $CompanyUpdateFile
```

The code above will fail because it cant use "$Company" in line 2

If I use this insteadt everything works fine.

```
$CompanyURLFile = "https://onegeek.dk/MSI/CYPL.rar"
```

How do I fix this

Comment: what are the contents of the Company.txt? generally if the contents of this file is a single string - this should work fine

Comment: The textfile contains only a simple string eg. : CYPL

Comment: It works fine for me in that case: `$company = Get-Content "somefile"` , `$CompanyURLFile = "https://onegeek.dk/MSI/$Company.rar"`, `$CompanyURLFile`, `https://onegeek.dk/MSI/CYPL.rar`

Comment: If the textfile really does contain just a single string your code should work.  I'd look at the text files for any extra information.  You could try 
    $Company = Get-Content "C:\ProgramData\test\Company.txt" | Select-Object -First 1 
to eliminate any spurious lines.

Comment: "| Select-Object -First 1" did the trick. there was 2 empty lines in the text file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add "| Select-Object -
    First 1"

```
$Company = Get-Content "C:\ProgramData\test\Company.txt" | Select-Object -    
First 1
$CompanyURLFile = "https://onegeek.dk/MSI/$Company.rar"
$CompanyUpdateFile="C:\ProgramData\test\conf\conf.rar"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $CompanyURLFile -OutFile $CompanyUpdateFile
```

Comment: You should also be able to do `Get-Content "C:\ProgramData\test\Company.txt" -TotalCount 1` to get just the first line.